# MergerFS Not Properly Using Disk Space

Tags: hard-disk, raid

I am pooling drives together with mergerfs using the following command:

`mergerfs -o defaults,allow_other,use_ino /media/pool\* /media/merger`

which pools all drives mounted starting with /media/pool to /media/merger. It combines them but when I try to move a very large file to /media/merger, it doesn't put it on a drive where it will fit. It's a 50GB file and it's trying to put it on a drive that only has a few GB available so the transfer fails. The other drives have enough space but it isn't trying to put it there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the documentation? There is no such thing as "copying a file." It's open, write x N, close. There isn't a way to know the size of the file ahead of time. The drive is selected at creation time and the create policy dictates that. By default it's `epmfs` which will choose the drive with the most free space which has the relative path being used.

If you want to keep a path preserving policy and have these kinds of situations handled look at the `moveonenospc` feature.

Comment: when I say copy a file I mean that I was copying from a drive (Not in my pool) to my pool.

Comment: Your solution should still apply though. I've remounted with it and am trying it out.

Comment: Seems to be working. I'd somehow glossed over that option in the docs. thanks

Comment: Where the file is copied from doesn't make a difference.

My suggestion is to not use a path preserving policy unless that's explicitly what you want. If you just want the drive with the most free space picked for new files then set the policy to `mfs`. The cost of moveonenospc is high since it must move files around. It's meant as a safeguard, like minfreespace. Not something that should happen much.